# cookies in winforms

Tags: winforms, cookies

I want to save user name and password in a cookie.mine is a win forms application.Please advice   how can we do this.

Thanks

Comment: we dont have a feature like cookie in winforms. cookie is a web side functionality that will store in user browser. If you want to save user namd and password just go for files. create a text file and save user name and password in that and save it in the application directory only

Answer (score 1):

In win Forms you should use registry,files,databases.... not cookies, cookies for web applications that usually be displayed in web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a password protected SQLite database (see [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)) and storing whatever you want there.

Also, do remember to [hash your passwords](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5794732.html)!

Answer (score 1):

This is not supposed to be an answers - more of a comment.  Apologies if I posted it in the wrong way:

I expect the person asking the question may be aware that this is not the optimal way to store info in a winforms app.  I would also like to know how to do this as a possible way of passing information from a website to a desktop app?  For example you want the same app to do different things depending on information pass to the app from the website.

I've found that you can  Retrieve Query String Information in a ClickOnce Application (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242.aspx) which allows you to pass information from a site to an app.  I want to know if cookies could also be used to do this.

I suspect it would be difficult and not practical in many situations to read info from a cookie in this way.  One way I can think of doing this is putting a GUID in a cookie and also hardcoing that GUID into the app and running a find in files over the computer to find it.  I realise that's a very ugly method but I would like to know what's possible.

I suppose another way might be to embeded a Webbrowser control in a winforms app and get the Webbrowser control to load a page containing JavaScript which reads that cookie.  You would then need some way of passing that back to the .NET code though?

Answer (score 0):

First, we can't use Cookies in WinForm applications.. it's a Web side functionality, but you can do something else..

For instance, once I had to do the same thing... to save the latest user connected to the application. I did it with a database (I prefere database, because txt files are not that safe.. we can erase them by mistake..)

So I suggest to save the username (and password in your case) on the database after every Connection event.

Hope that was usefull.